# I need expert advice to print the time in hours minutes and sec

Tags: output

```
nt main() {
    int hh,mm,ss;
    char time[2];
    printf("enter the time");
    scanf("%d %d %d %s",&hh,&mm,&ss,&time);
    printf("%d",ss);
    printf("hh:mm:ss time:%d:%d:%d %s",hh,mm,ss,time);
    //for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    //printf("%c",time[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this program that it's every time gets printed with 0 if the input is any non zero integer

Comment: thank you so much for the reply and i will take your inputs to elaborate my question in a right way and ya the ans helped me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all give more information when posting a question, rather than just why does this not work...

Now about the code.

For starters **gcc** wouldn't even let me compile this, because you dont use the **&** sign when reading an array of characters. And never allocate a small number of memory to the array of characters, especially if you don't know the size of it.

Correct way:

```cpp
char time[100];
scanf(%s, time);
```

When I removed the `&` sign and compiled it worked as it should, however I have no idea what you wanted with the `char time[2];` so removed it and here is a perfectly working (more elegant) code, however do realize if you are scanning an integer do not supply the program a string!

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int hh,mm,ss;
    printf("Enter the time: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &hh, &mm, &ss);
    printf("hh:mm:ss time: %d:%d:%d\n", hh, mm, ss);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, neither you and I have enough rep to comment on each other so I will say it here :) If you think this helped please give the answer an up-vote and close the thread by accepting the answer, so people know this is the right thing.